# How to assign license in Microsoft Graph API version 5.19 c#?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

How to assign license in Microsoft Graph API version 5.19 c#?

When I searched online, I couldn't find a method that I could use on version 5 or higher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you try to upgrade to v5 this library has a breaking changes from this article https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md

The first step you need to get token like this

```
var interactiveBrowserCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(interactiveBrowserCredentialOptions);
var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(interactiveBrowserCredential);
```

or like custom authentication flows can be done creating an implementation of IAccessTokenProvider

```
public class TokenProvider : IAccessTokenProvider
{
    public Task<string> GetAuthorizationTokenAsync(Uri uri, Dictionary<string, object> additionalAuthenticationContext = default,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var token = "token";
        // get the token and return it in your own way
        return Task.FromResult(token);
    }

    public AllowedHostsValidator AllowedHostsValidator { get; }
}
```

Creating instance of GraphServiceClientCreating

```
var authenticationProvider = new BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider(new YourAuthenticationProvider()); // Authorization method
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);
```

Insert your licences for removing and adding. Make sure that this data has value in licensesToRemove or licensesToAdd

```
var licensesToRemove = new List<Guid?> { };
var license = new AssignedLicense { SkuId = "yourLicenceId" };
List<AssignedLicense> licensesToAdd = new List<AssignedLicense> { license };
```

Make query

```
await graphClient.Users["yourUserId"].AssignLicense.PostAsync(new Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.AssignLicense.AssignLicensePostRequestBody()
    {
        RemoveLicenses = licensesToRemove,
        AddLicenses = licensesToAdd
    });
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: Hello Alex, can you please elaborate on the code, explain why you think your answer is helpful. Just posting code, isn't enough.

Comment: Thanks, i only used last 2 steps and that worked.