# When i try to assign a license i get an error Microsoft Graph API C# 5.21

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

When i try to assign a license i get Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError: 'Exception_WasThrown' error, heres my code:

Part1:

```
        private static async Task<bool> EpostaKontrol(string eposta, GraphServiceClient graphClient)
    {
        var users = await graphClient.Users[eposta].GetAsync();
        if (users.AccountEnabled == true)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    private async void ButtonKullanıcıAç_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //CSV'yi Hazırla
        var csv = new StringBuilder();
        csv.AppendLine("Kullanıcı Adı,Parola,Mail Adresi,İsim,Telefon");
        var dosyaSecildi = false;

        while (!dosyaSecildi)
        {
            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                dosyaSecildi = true;
                filePath = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Lütfen bir dosya seçiniz.");
                filePath = string.Empty;
            }
        }

        var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
        {
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
        };

        var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
        //Progressbar'ı hazırla
        int kullanıcı_sayısı = satır_sayısı;
        int artis = 100 / kullanıcı_sayısı;
        progressBar1.Step = artis;
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
        progressBar1.Visible = true;
        int i = 2;
        int satır = 1;
        using var reader2 = new StreamReader(file);
        {
            while (!reader2.EndOfStream)
            {
                if (satır == 1)
                {
                    reader2.ReadLine();
                    satır++;
                    continue;
                }
                // CSV'yi Okumaya Hazırla
                string line = reader2.ReadLine();
                string[] values = line.Split(',');
                Console.WriteLine(line[3]);
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                try
                {
                    // Kullanıcıyı Aç
                    string isim = values[3];
                    string Mail = isim.Trim().Replace(" ", string.Empty).ToLower();
                    Mail = Tr_to_ASCII(Mail);
                    var userprincipalname = $"{Mail}@onlinedersmerkezi.com";
                    var user = new User
                    {
                        AccountEnabled = true,
                        DisplayName = isim,
                        MailNickname = Mail,
                        UserPrincipalName = userprincipalname,
                        PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
                        {
                            ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false,
                            Password = textBox1.Text
                        },
                        UsageLocation = "TR",

                        AssignedLicenses = new List<AssignedLicense>
                        {
                            new AssignedLicense
                            {
                                SkuId = Guid.Parse("314c4481-f395-4525-be8b-2ec4bb1e9d91"),
                            }
                        }

                    };
                    Console.WriteLine(user.MailNickname);
                    Console.WriteLine(user.UserPrincipalName);
                    await graphClient.Users.PostAsync(user);
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    // !Kullanıcıyı Aç

                    // CSV Adlı Değişkene Kullanıcıyı Yaz
                    var newLine = string.Format($"{userprincipalname},{textBox1.Text},{values[2]},{values[3]},{values[4]}");
                    csv.AppendLine(newLine);
                    progressBar1.PerformStep();
                    Console.WriteLine(reader2.EndOfStream);
                    // !CSV Adlı Değişkene Kullanıcıyı Yaz
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    // Kullanıcıyı Aç
                    // Kullanıcı Adı Kullanılmış Mı Kontrol Et Varsa i'yi Arttır
                    string isim = values[3];
                    string Mail = isim.Trim().Replace(" ", string.Empty).ToLower();
                    Mail = Tr_to_ASCII(Mail);
                    var userprincipalname = Mail + "_" + i + "@onlinedersmerkezi.com";
                    while (await EpostaKontrol(userprincipalname, graphClient))
                    {
                        userprincipalname = Mail + "_" + i + "@onlinedersmerkezi.com";
                        i++;
                    }
                    // !Kullanıcı Adı Kullanılmış Mı Kontrol Et Varsa i'yi Arttır

                    var user = new User
                    {
                        AccountEnabled = true,
                        DisplayName = isim,
                        MailNickname = Mail,
                        UserPrincipalName = userprincipalname,
                        PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
                        {
                            ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false,
                            Password = textBox1.Text
                        },
                        UsageLocation = "TR"
                    };

                    Console.WriteLine(user.MailNickname);
                    Console.WriteLine(user.UserPrincipalName);
                    await graphClient.Users.PostAsync(user);
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    // !Kullanıcıyı Aç

                    // CSV Adlı Değişkene Kullanıcıyı Yaz
                    var newLine = string.Format($"{userprincipalname},{textBox1.Text},{values[2]},{values[3]},{values[4]}");
                    csv.AppendLine(newLine);
                    progressBar1.PerformStep();
                    // !CSV Adlı Değişkene Kullanıcıyı Yaz
                }
            }
        }

        // CSV Dosyasını Kaydet
        File.WriteAllText(path: filePath, contents: csv.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show("İşlem tamamlandı");
        progressBar1.Visible = false;
        // !CSV Dosyasını Kaydet
    }
```

Part2:

```
private async void ButtonLisans_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
        {
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
        };
        var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

        int satır = 1;
        using var reader2 = new StreamReader(file);
        {
            while (!reader2.EndOfStream)
            {
                if (satır == 1)
                {
                    reader2.ReadLine();
                    satır++;
                    continue;
                }
                string line = reader2.ReadLine();
                string[] values = line.Split(',');
                Console.WriteLine(line[3]);
                int artis = (100 / satır_sayısı) + 1;
                progressBar2.Step = artis;
                progressBar2.Value = 0;
                progressBar2.Visible = true;

                if (satır == 1)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                try
                {
                    var userQuery = await graphClient.Users[values[0]].GetAsync();

                    var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.AssignLicense.AssignLicensePostRequestBody
                    {
                        AddLicenses = new List<AssignedLicense>{
                            new AssignedLicense
                            {
                                DisabledPlans = new List<Guid?>
                                {
                                     new Guid { },
                                },
                                SkuId = Guid.Parse("314c4481-f395-4525-be8b-2ec4bb1e9d91"),
                            },
                        },
                        RemoveLicenses = new List<Guid?>
                        {
                             new Guid { },
                        },
                    };

                    await graphClient.Users[userQuery.Id].AssignLicense.PostAsync(requestBody);
                    progressBar2.PerformStep();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var msg = MessageBox.Show("Bir hata oluştu. Bu hatanın muhtemel sebebi {values[0]} adında bir kullanıcı olmamasıdır. Eğer hatanın bu olmadığına eminseniz Evet butonuna basın.",
                        "Hata", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    if (msg == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show($"Bu hata mesajını lütfen info@onlinedersmerkezi.com e-posta adresine e-posta olarak gönderin: {ex.Message}");
                    }
                }
            }
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            MessageBox.Show("İşlem tamamlandı");
            progressBar2.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

I searched for the solution on the Internet, but I could not find it.

Edit: I solwed this problem using this post: [How to assign license in Microsoft Graph API version 5.19 c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76589754/how-to-assign-license-in-microsoft-graph-api-version-5-19-c/77113226#77113226)

Comment: I solwed this problem using this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76589754/how-to-assign-license-in-microsoft-graph-api-version-5-19-c/77113226#77113226

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this code

`DisabledPlans = new List<Guid?> { new Guid { }, },`